# Prisma: Getting error when trying to search by id with findUniqe

Tags: sqlite, next.js, prisma

I'm trying to do a PATCH and GET request with findUnique in prisma, searching with id, but it's not giving back anything,either I get error 500 or PrismaClientValidation Error. POST request is working and GET request with findmany as well. I don't know what I should write differently to make this work.

app/api/contacts/[id]/route.ts - This is not working

```
import { type NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import prisma from '@/libs/prismaClient';

type Params = {
    params: {
        id: number;
    };
};

export const GET = async (req: NextRequest, { params }: Params) => {
    try {
        const { id } = params;
        const contact = await prisma.contact.findUnique({
            where: {
                id,
            },
        });
        return NextResponse.json(contact);
    } catch (error) {
        return NextResponse.json({ message: 'GET error' }, { status: 500 });
    }
};
```

app/api/contacts/route.ts - This works

```
import { type NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import prisma from '@/libs/prismaClient';

export const GET = async () => {
    try {
        const contacts = await prisma.contact.findMany();
        return NextResponse.json(contacts);
    } catch (error) {
        return NextResponse.json({ message: 'GET error' }, { status: 500 });
    }
};
```

prisma/schema.prisma

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "sqlite"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model Contact {
  id    Int     @id @unique @default(autoincrement())
  name  String
  phone String
  email String  @unique
  avatarUrl String
}
```

libs/prismaClient.ts

```
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';

declare global {
    namespace NodeJS {
        interface Global {}
    }
}

interface CustomNodeJsGlobal extends NodeJS.Global {
    prisma: PrismaClient;
}

declare const global: CustomNodeJsGlobal;

const prisma = global.prisma || new PrismaClient();

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') global.prisma = prisma;

export default prisma;
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@prisma/client": "^5.3.1",
    "next": "13.5.4",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "autoprefixer": "^10",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.5.4",
    "postcss": "^8",
    "prisma": "^5.3.1",
    "tailwindcss": "^3",
    "typescript": "^5"
  }
}
```

Comment: what does id log if you console log it? const { id } = params;